# how beacon detect major and minor more than 1?

Tags: android, beacon, altbeacon

I got a project from college to make a pop up notification

so, i made my phone as a beacon. and make validation for get a notification by detecting major and minor from it's beacon.

so i will post major and minor after detecting some beacon,but i got spamming from this code, so at log i got the same major and minor continously,how can i post major and minor once if beacon one, and post twice with different major and minor if beacon two etc

```
`@Override
public void onBeaconServiceConnect() {
    beaconManager.removeAllRangeNotifiers();
    beaconManager.addRangeNotifier(new RangeNotifier() {
        @Override
        public void didRangeBeaconsInRegion(Collection<Beacon> beacons, Region region) {
            for (Beacon temp : beacons) {
                    if (beacons.size() > 0) {
                        MajorBeacon MajID = new MajorBeacon("Major:"+temp.getId2().toString(),"Minor"+temp.getId3().toString());

                        MajID.setMajor(temp.getId2().toString());
                        Log.i(TAG, "The first beacon I see is about " + beacons.iterator().next().getDistance() + " meters away.");
                 Log.i(TAG2,"Hello major id kamu:"+MajID.getMajor());
                        Log.i(TAG3,"Hello minor id kamu:33");
                       Post(MajID);
                    }

            }
        }
    });


    try {
        beaconManager.startRangingBeaconsInRegion(new Region("myRangingUniqueId",null , null, null));
    } catch (RemoteException e) {    }
}
```

`

Answer (score 1):

Okay lets have some pseudo code  for your problem.

```
    ArrayList<Beacon> searchedBeaconsList = new ArrayList(); // Declare it global
    if(searchedBeaconsList != null && searchedBeaconsList.isEmpty){
    searchedBeaconsList.add(searchedBeacon) 
    }else if(!searchedBeaconsList.contains(searchedBeacon)){
    searchedBeaconsList.add(searchedBeacon)
   }
```

in this way you will always get single beacon at a time and other spamming will be rejected and also clear list while leaving the screen or app is destroyed.

I hope this will solve your problem.

Comment: This is a good way to solve this problem.  Understand that the didRangeBeaconsInRegion is designed to give you a callback every ~1 sec with a list of all visible beacons.  If you only want to know each time a distinct beacon appears you can use code like shown in this answer.  Be aware, however, that each time your app restarts the searchedBeaconsList will be cleared, so then detections wills tart over.  Similarly, if the app has been running in the background for hours (even days) then the list is retained, giving possibly surprising results when a beacon detection is not considered new.